# Get last insert id of new record in FileMaker Pro database

Tags: filemaker

I have some data in a field that looks like this

boston,11/7/10,11/12/10,11/13/10
atlanta,11/11/10,11/15/10,11/18/10

and what I want o do is make this relational instead of being in a field by itself

so what I have so far is I can get it to alert me each item keeping track of iterations and such
Then I get to Boston and say ok I'm going to insert "boston" into my citys table which just has a name and id then I get to the first date and I say ok I'll insert this into the dates table which will have a date , id and city_id fields and there comes the problem how do I know what kind the city id would be for that date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is covered [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101214/filemaker-pro-10-how-to-get-the-unique-id-of-last-insert-on-mysql-tables-odbc)